# Find record, that has ALL associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, find, has-and-belongs-to-many

Say,

we have a "Person" and "Favorite" models.

"Favorite" is what this person likes: "music", "video", "sport", "internet", "traveling" etc.

"Person" HABTM "Favorites", and "Favorite" HABTM "Persons"

I need to find a Person, that has ALL listed "Favorites. For example, find a person, that likes "music", "traveling" and "sport".

How it can be done, using ActiveRecord.find method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@people = Person.find(:all, 
   :joins => :favourites,
   :select => "person.*, count(favourites) favourite_count", 
   :conditions => {:favourites => @array_of_favourites}, 
   :group => "persons.id having favourite_count = #{@array_of_favourites.count}")
```

You'll need something like this to find people with **all** favourites rather than *any combination of* favourites. This is based on the assumption that you have an array of favourite objects, rather than a collection of strings.

**Rails 4 compatible solution:**

```
@people = Person.joins(:favourites)
  .where(favourites: { id: @array_of_favourites })
  .group("people.id")
  .having("count(favourites.id) = #{@array_of_favourites.count}")
```