# ActiveRecord: How do I find records by all of their associated records?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, many-to-many

With ActiveRecord you can pass a field and an array into WHERE like so:

```
Product.joins(:category).where('category.id' => [x,y,z])
```

(in this case Product has a many to many relationship with Category)

This uses the IN operator to find all products in categories with an ID of x, y, or z

What I would like to do is find all products in categories with an ID of x, y, AND z. I know you can produce this sort of result like so:

```
Product.joins(:category).where('category.id' => x).where('category.id' => y).where('category.id' => z)
```

In other words, I want to find products that have all of the categories supplied.

I feel like I could do be doing something much simpler here. Any ideas?

---

Update: I believe [this question is relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416451/find-record-that-has-all-associated-records), still having trouble getting it to work. Still think there might be another way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Havent tried... but something like below should give you hint to get started -

```
Product.joins(:categories).select("products.*, GROUP_CONCAT('categories.id') as category_ids").group('products.id').having('category_ids = ?', [1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Product.joins(:category)
    .where('category.id = ? AND category.id = ? AND category.id = ?',x,y,z)
```