# Only return associative records that include all IDs in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Say I have the following tables and relationships:

`class Book
  has_many :book_genres
end`

`class Genre
  has_many :book_genres
end`

`class BookGenre
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :genre
end`

If I wanted to only find the books that have two specific genre IDs (13005 and 9190),

I was thinking I could do something like:

`Book.where(book_genres: {genre_id: [13005, 9190]})`

But it's returning books that have either Genres of ID 13005 OR 9190.

I also thought maybe I could filter it down by doing something like:

`Book.where(book_genres: {genre_id: [13005]}).where(book_genres: {genre_id: [9190]})`

But that's not working either.

How would I only find the Books that contain Genres with both IDs?

Notes:

From this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3416838/1778314), I tried doing this:

`Book.joins(:book_genres).where(book_genres: { genre_id: [13005,9190]}).group("books.id").having("count(book_genres.id) = #{[13005, 9190].count}")`

But this doesn't work either (returns both sets).

Additionally, there's a similar post using Recipes and Ingredients with no working solution: [Ruby On Rails 5, activerecord query where model association ids includes ALL ids in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990859/ruby-on-rails-5-activerecord-query-where-model-association-ids-includes-all-ids)

Answer (score 1):

Books that have two specific genre IDs (13005 and 9190),

```
book_ids_either_have_two_ids = Book. includes(:book_genres).where("book_genres.id IN ?= [3005 9190]")distinct.pluck(:id)

Book.where.not("id IN ?", book_ids_either_have_two_ids)
```

Comment: using  `includes` rather than `joins` will be more efficient for small datasets.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Thanks for your suggestion :) can you please cross check it if this query is correct, also i'm open  for your suggestion to make this query more efficient . thanks :)

Comment: My apologies, my original statement is not quite accurate. if using includes - this will prevent additional database queries being fired, if for example, you want to access the `genres` records. But if the `genres` records are not being accessed then it won't be any more efficient than `joins`. in other words, `includes` loads the table into the memory. lastly, the sql is inefficient, OP wants the result where both 3005 and 9190 exists, and `IN` is basically an `OR` operator in SQL. you would have to used `AND` in the query to make it work. my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

I know following is not proficient way to do but can solve your problem,

```
Book.includes(:book_genres).select { |book| book.book_genres.map(&:genre_id).uniq.sort == [9190, 13005] }
```

Above will return ouput in `Array` type instead of `ActiveRecord::Relation` but it will work as per your requirement.

Comment: Though it will work but it's not efficient way, as `select{|book| book....}` will iterate each records one by one to satisfy condition.

Comment: @Gabbar Yes, I know so I added `includes` but still it will not be efficient. Need to do by raw sql implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`Book.joins(:book_genres).where(book_genres: { genre_id: [13005, 205580]}).group("books.id").having('count(books.id) >= ?', [13005, 205580].size)`